# Is $SU(2)\times U(1) = U(2)$?

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, topology, lie-algebra, group-representations

In the many textbook of the Standard Model, I encounter the relation 
\begin{align}
SU(2)_L \times U(1)_L = U(2)_L.
\end{align}
Here the subscript $L$ means the left-handness (i.e., the chirality of the fermions). 
Is the relation above true in the general case? That is, is
\begin{align}
SU(2) \times U(1) = U(2)\ ?
\end{align}

Comment: It's my understanding that the subscripts on these groups are merely labels to remind us of the objects they are acting on. So we write $SU(3)_C$ or $SU(3)_F$ depending on whether we're considering the group $SU(3)$ to be acting on the triplet of colour states of a quark, or the flavour triplet (up, down, strange). It's precisely the same group in both cases. Hence removing the labels is entirely legitimate. At least, I think. I would also say that I'm pretty sure the isomorphism is in fact
$$ SU(2) \times U(1) = U(2) \times Z_2 $$
Perhaps somebody could explain why books often drop the $Z_2$?

Comment: Related math.SE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111766/11127

Comment: @gj255 - it's not true that $\mathrm{SU}(2) \times \mathrm{U}(1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{U}(2) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  The easiest way to see this is to note that $\mathrm{SU}(2) \times \mathrm{U}(1)$ is connected, while $\mathrm{U}(2) \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has two connected components.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. The relevant Lie group isomorphism reads

   > $$\begin{align} U(2)~\cong~&[U(1)\times SU(2)]/\mathbb{Z}_2, \cr 
   > Z(SU(2))~\cong~&\mathbb{Z}_2.\end{align}\tag{1a} $$

   In detail, the Lie group isomorphism (1a) is given by
   $$U(2)~\ni~ g\quad\mapsto\quad $$
   $$ \left(\sqrt{\det g}, ~\frac{g}{\sqrt{\det g}}\right) ~\sim~ \left(-\sqrt{\det g}, ~-\frac{g}{\sqrt{\det g}}\right)$$
   $$~\in ~[U(1)\times SU(2)]/\mathbb{Z}_2.\tag{1b}$$
   Here the $\sim$ symbol denotes a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-equivalence relation. The $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action resolves the ambiguity in the definition of the double-valued square root.
2. It seems natural to mention that the Lie group isomorphism (1a) generalizes in a straightforward manner to generic (indefinite) [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) ([super](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergroup_(physics))) groups

   > $$\begin{align} U(p,q|m)~\cong~&[U(1)\times SU(p,q|m)]/\mathbb{Z}_{|n-m|}, \cr
   > Z( SU(p,q|m))~\cong~&\mathbb{Z}_{|n-m|},\end{align}\tag{2a}$$

   where
   $$\begin{align} p,q,m~\in~& \mathbb{N}_0, \cr n~\equiv~p+q~\neq~&m,  \cr 
   n+m~\geq ~& 1,\end{align}\tag{2b}$$ are three integers. Note that the number $n$ of bosonic dimensions is assumed to be different from the number $m$ of fermionic dimensions. In detail, the Lie group isomorphism (2a) is given by
   $$U(p,q|m)~\ni~ g\quad\mapsto\quad $$
   $$ \left(\sqrt[|n-m|]{{\rm sdet} g}, ~\frac{g}{\sqrt[|n-m|]{{\rm sdet} g}}\right) ~\sim~ \left(\omega^k~\sqrt[|n-m|]{{\rm sdet} g}, ~\frac{g}{\omega^k~\sqrt[|n-m|]{{\rm sdet} g}}\right)$$
   $$ ~\in ~[U(1)\times SU(p,q|m)]/\mathbb{Z}_{|n-m|},\tag{2c}$$
   where $$\omega~:=~\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{|n\!-\!m|}\right)\tag{2d}$$
   is a $|n\!-\!m|$'th root of unity, and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
3. Interestingly, in the case with the same number of bosonic and fermionic dimensions $n=m$, the [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory))
   $$  Z( SU(p,q|m))~\cong~U(1) \tag{3a}$$
   becomes continuous! I.e. the $U(1)$-center of $U(p,q|m)$ has moved inside $SU(p,q|m)$, and formula (2a) no longer holds!

Comment: Notes for later: Define non-central(!) diagonal elements $D(\lambda):={\rm diag} (\underbrace{\lambda,~\ldots~, \lambda}_{n\text{ bosonic entries}}, \underbrace{\lambda^{-1},~\ldots~, \lambda^{-1}}_{m\text{ fermionic entries}} )$;  Define semidirect product by $(\mu, g) \ltimes (\nu, h):= (\mu\nu, D(\nu)^{-1}gD(\nu) h)$;

Comment: Notes for later: $$U(p,q|m)~\cong~[U(1)\times SU(p,q|m)]/\mathbb{Z}_{|p+q-m|}\quad\text{if}\quad n\equiv p+q\neq m;$$ $$U(p,q|m)~\cong~[U(1)\ltimes SU(p,q|m)]/\mathbb{Z}_{p+q+m};$$ $$GL(n|m;\mathbb{F})~\cong~[\mathbb{F}^{\times} \times SL(n|m;\mathbb{F})]/\mathbb{Z}_{|n-m|}\quad\text{if}\quad n\neq m;$$ $$GL(n|m;\mathbb{F})~\cong~[\mathbb{F}^{\times} \ltimes SL(n|m;\mathbb{F})]/\mathbb{Z}_{n+m};$$

Comment: Notes for later: $$U(p,q|m)~\ni~ g\quad\mapsto\quad $$
$$ \left(\sqrt[n+m]{{\rm sdet} g}, ~D\left(\sqrt[n+m]{{\rm sdet} g}\right)^{-1}g\right)  \quad\sim\quad\left(\omega^k~\sqrt[n+m]{{\rm sdet} g}, ~D\left(\omega^k~\sqrt[n+m]{{\rm sdet} g}\right)^{-1}g\right) $$
$$ ~\in ~[U(1)\ltimes SU(p,q|m)]/\mathbb{Z}_{n+m};$$

Comment: That was very useful

Comment: Similarly can I then write $$S(U(n) \times U(m))$$ $$ \backsimeq (U(1) \times SU(n) \times SU(m))/ \mathbb{Z}_{n+m}$$ ?

Comment: Hi @R. Rankin. Thanks for the feedback. See my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176575/2451).