# How do I decompose an $SO(10)$ antisymmetric tensor in $SO(4) \times SU(3) \times U(1)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, group-theory, representation-theory

My guess is that If I denote the $SO(4)$ indices $\mu, \nu = 1,...4$  and the $SU(3)$ indices by $I,J=1,2,3$, I think $N^{mn}$ should decompose as $N^{\mu \nu}, N^{IJ}, N^{I}_J, N_{IJ}$ plus other terms with mixed indices $I,\mu$, which I don't know how to determine.

I would appreciate if someone could give an explanation of an honest way to decompose $SO(10)$ in $SO(4) \times SU(3) \times U(1)$.

Comment: Due diligence: have you absorbed the totality and methods of Slansky's review?

Comment: $S^2\boldsymbol{10}$ decomposes as $(\boldsymbol1,\boldsymbol1)_0+(\boldsymbol4,\boldsymbol3)_{-1}+(\boldsymbol4,\overline{\boldsymbol3})_{+1}+(\boldsymbol9,\boldsymbol1)_0+(\boldsymbol1,\boldsymbol6)_{-2}+(\boldsymbol1,\overline{\boldsymbol6})_{+2}+(\boldsymbol1,\boldsymbol8)_0$ and
$A^2\boldsymbol{10}$ decomposes as

Comment: $(\boldsymbol1,\boldsymbol1)_0+(\boldsymbol1,\boldsymbol3)_{+2}+(\boldsymbol1,\overline{\boldsymbol3})_{-2}+(\boldsymbol3,\boldsymbol1)_{0}+(\overline{\boldsymbol3},\boldsymbol1)_{0}+(\boldsymbol4,\boldsymbol3)_{-1}+(\boldsymbol4,\overline{\boldsymbol3})_{+1}+(\boldsymbol1,\boldsymbol8)_0$
under $\mathfrak{so}_{10}\supset\mathfrak{so}_4+\mathfrak{su}_3+\mathfrak u_1$, unless I messed it up. So double check. In any case this is a math question.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform What do you mean by $S^2 \textbf{10}$ and $A^2 \textbf{10}$ ?

Comment: Ignoring [Slansky](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf) if you are studying group theory in GUTs is not an option. Start from table 43.

Comment: @CosmasZachos It seems very useful, but it doesn't have $SO(10)$ in terms of $SO(4) \times SU(3) \times U(1)$.

Comment: SO(4) ~ SU(2)xSU(2) at the algebra level. Do due diligence. Surely, you don't want a one liner for your homework?

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

1. Firstly,
   $$SO(10) ~\supseteq~ SO(4)\times SO(6),\tag{1}$$
   so we get the [branching rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation)
   $$ {\bf 10}~\stackrel{(1)}{\cong}~({\bf 4},{\bf 1}) \oplus ({\bf 1},{\bf 6}),\tag{2}$$
   and
   $${\bf 10}\wedge{\bf 10}~\stackrel{(2)}{\cong}~ ({\bf 4}\wedge{\bf 4},{\bf 1})\oplus ({\bf 4},{\bf 6})\oplus ({\bf 1},{\bf 6}\wedge{\bf 6}).\tag{3}$$
   Here the space of 2-forms
   $$ {\bf 4}\wedge{\bf 4}~\cong~{\bf 3}_+\oplus{\bf 3}_-\tag{4}$$
   splits into selfdual/antiselfdual parts under 4D [Hodge duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator).
2. Secondly,
   $$SO(6)~\supseteq~ U(3)~\cong~[SU(3)\times U(1)]/\mathbb{Z}_3,\tag{5}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169087/2451) Phys.SE post. Up until now the vector spaces under point 1 could in principle be real. In particular the [representations are real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_representation). Now we complexify the vector spaces. We get the branching rules
   $$ {\bf 6}~\stackrel{(5)}{\cong}~{\bf 3}_1 \oplus \bar{\bf 3}_{-1},\tag{6}$$
   and
   $$\begin{align} {\bf 6}\wedge{\bf 6}
   ~\stackrel{(6)}{\cong}~&({\bf 3}\wedge{\bf 3})_2 
   \oplus (\bar{\bf 3}\wedge\bar{\bf 3})_{-2}
   \oplus ({\bf 3}\otimes\bar{\bf 3})_0 \cr
   ~\cong~&\bar{\bf 3}_2 \oplus {\bf 3}_{-2}
   \oplus ({\bf 8}_0 \oplus {\bf 1}_0) 
   ,\end{align}\tag{7}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167680/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: 1. You said that ${\bf 6}~{\cong}~{\bf 3}_1 \oplus \bar{\bf 3}_{-1}$, so that in your last equation shouldn't be ${\bf \bar{3}}_{-2} \oplus {\bf 3}_2$ instead?

Comment: 2. If I understood your answer correctly, the components of $N^{mn}$ that I defined in the question should decompose as $$N^{\mu \nu} \oplus N^{IJ} \oplus N_{IJ} \oplus N^I_{\;J} \oplus N^{\mu}_I \oplus N^{\mu I} ~\cong~ ({\bf 4} \wedge {\bf 4}) \oplus {\bf 3}_2 \oplus {\bf \bar{3}}_{-2} \oplus {\bf 8}_0 \oplus {\bf 1}_0 \oplus ({\bf 4} \otimes { \bf \bar{3}})_{-1} \oplus ({\bf 4} \otimes { \bf 3})_{1},$$ is that right?

Comment: 1. No, the 3D Hodge duality doesn't act on the $U(1)$ factor.

Comment: Can you write the answer in terms of the tensor $N^{mn}$ so that I can accept the answer?