# Is $U(n)\simeq SU(n)\times U(1)$

Tags: group-theory, unitarity

As the title suggests, my question is does $U(n)\simeq SU(n)\times U(1)$ for general $n$?

If so, how does one prove it?

If not, is at least $U(n)\supset SU(n)\times U(1)$? What is the group $\frac{U(n)}{SU(n)\times U(1)}$ in that case?

Comment: $U(N)\simeq SU(N)\times U(1)/{\mathbb Z}_N$, because the factorization into $SU(N)$ and phase is not unique. You can pass $N$-th roots of unity between the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169087/2451