# Why is it that every locally conformal transformation can be extended to a global conformal transformation for $D>2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, topology, lie-algebra

In $D=2$, we can have locally analytic transformations that cannot be globally well-defined.

However, for CFTs in $D>2$, we have only the global group. Why is that?

Also, is it a statement that depends on topology? Any references on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}^{p,q}}$ denote the [conformal compactification](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=conformal+compactification) of $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$. Let $n:=p+q$ denote the dimension.
2. (The pseudo-Riemannian generalization of) [Liouville's rigidity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28conformal_mappings%29) states that if $n\geq 3$, then all local conformal transformations of $\overline{\mathbb{R}^{p,q}}$ can be extended to global conformal transformations. For a proof, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391624/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. The upshot of Liouville's rigidity theorem is that for $n\geq 3$ there are only relatively few local conformal transformations of $\overline{\mathbb{R}^{p,q}}$ [which consist of (composition of) translations, similarities, orthogonal transformations and inversions], and these are easily extendable to global ones.
4. On the other hand, for $n=2$, there are many more local conformal transformations. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108472/2451) Phys.SE post.
5. Similar rigidity results (in the smooth case) hold on any conformal manifold $M$, cf. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28conformal_mappings%29).

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I knew how the distinction between d=2,3 arises in the derivation of conformal maps, but wanted to know if that was explained in detail somewhere. This helps.

Comment: There is still the question about topology, and the business of finding conformal transformations in manifolds that are not conformally related to flat space.