# Topological/Geometrical justification for $\text{CFT}_2$ being special

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, topology, lie-algebra

It is known as a fact that conformal maps on $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>2$ are rotations, dilations, translations, and special transformations while conformal maps for $n=2$ are from a much wider class of maps, holomorphic/antiholomorphic maps. I was wondering to know if there is any topological or geometrical description for this.

To show what I mean, consider this example: in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>2$ interchanging particles can only change the wave function to itself or its minus. It is related to the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^n-x_0$ ($x_0$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^n-\{x_0\})=e$ for $n>2$) but this is not true for $n=2$.

I want to know whether exists any topological invariant or just any geometrical explanation that is related to the fact that I mentioned about conformal maps on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Minor suggestion: Replace $\text{CFT}_2$ in title with 2D CFT, which may be easier to understand.

Answer (score 14):

This is essentially [Liouville's rigidity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)) for conformal mappings in $\color{red}{n\geq 3}$ dimensions. Interestingly, the cause is local rigidity [rather than global topological obstructions]. For a proof see Refs. 1 & 2.

Combined with the fact that every mapping in $\color{red}{n=1}$ dimension is automatically conformal, it is perhaps not totally surprising that the border case $\color{red}{n=2}$ is special. In fact, there are infinitely many (dimensions of) local conformal deformations for $\color{red}{1\leq n\leq 2}$.

The main point is the following Lemma.

> *Lemma.* In a coordinate neigborhood where the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is constant, the components $\varepsilon^{\mu}$ of every [conformal Killing vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_Killing_equation) (CKVF) is at most a quadratic polynomial in the coordinates $x^{\nu}$ [i.e. there are only finitely many (dimensions of) local conformal deformations] if $\color{red}{n\geq 3}$.

*Proof:* Conformal Killing equation (CKE):

$$\omega g_{\mu\nu}~=~\varepsilon_{\mu,\nu}+\varepsilon_{\nu,\mu} .\tag{1}$$

$$n \omega~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ 2\varepsilon^{\mu}{}_{,\mu}.\tag{2}$$

$$(\color{red}{2-n})\partial_{\mu}\omega ~\stackrel{(1)+(2)}{=}~  2\Box \varepsilon_{\mu}.\tag{3}$$

$$ (\color{red}{2-n})\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\omega ~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~ 2\Box\partial_{\mu} \varepsilon_{\nu} .\tag{4}$$

$$ 2(\color{red}{1-n})\Box \omega~\stackrel{(2)+(4)}{=}~0 \quad \stackrel{\color{red}{n\neq 1}}{\Rightarrow} \quad \Box \omega~=~0.\tag{5}$$

$$ ~(\color{red}{2-n})\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\omega~\stackrel{(1)+(4)}{=}~g_{\mu\nu} \Box \omega~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~0\quad \stackrel{\color{red}{n\neq 2}}{\Rightarrow} \quad \partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\omega~=~0.\tag{6}$$

Eq. (6) shows that

$$\omega~=~a_{\mu}x^{\mu}+b\tag{7}$$

is an [affine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation)$^1$ of $x^{\mu}$.

$$\varepsilon_{\mu,\nu\lambda}+\varepsilon_{\nu,\mu\lambda}~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ g_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\lambda}\omega \tag{8}$$

$$2\varepsilon_{\lambda,\mu\nu}~\stackrel{(8)}{=}~g_{\lambda\mu}\partial_{\nu}\omega +g_{\lambda\nu}\partial_{\mu}\omega -g_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\lambda}\omega ~\stackrel{(7)}{=}~\text{constant}.\tag{9}$$
$\Box$

References:

1. P. Ginsparg, *Applied Conformal Field Theory,*  [arXiv:hep-th/9108028](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028); p.5.
2. J. Slovak, *Natural Operator on Conformal manifolds,* Habilitation thesis 1993; p.46. A PS file is available [here](http://www.math.muni.cz/%7Eslovak/ftp/papers/vienna.ps) from the author's homepage. (Hat tip: [Vit Tucek](https://mathoverflow.net/a/60731/13917).)

--

$^1$ The parameters $a_{\mu}$ and $b$ in eq. (7) correspond to $n$ special conformal transformations and $1$ dilatation, respectively,

$$\varepsilon_{\mu}~=~\frac{\omega}{2}x_{\mu}-\frac{x^2}{4}\partial_{\mu}\omega
\quad \stackrel{(7)}{\Rightarrow} \quad
\varepsilon_{\mu,\nu}~=~\frac{\omega}{2}g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{x_{\mu}}{2}\partial_{\nu}\omega-\frac{x_{\nu}}{2}\partial_{\mu}\omega
.\tag{10}$$

Eq. (10) satisfies the CKE (1), which is an inhomogeneous 1st-order linear [PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation) in $\varepsilon_{\mu}$.  What other solutions are there? After subtracting the solution (10) from the CKE (1), we get the corresponding homogeneous 1st-order linear PDE, which is the [Killing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) (KE)

$$\varepsilon_{\mu,\nu}+\varepsilon_{\nu,\mu}~=~0\tag{11}$$

with

$$\omega~=~0.\tag{12}$$

Eqs. (9) & (12) now show that

$$\varepsilon_{\mu}~\stackrel{(9)+(12)}{=}~a_{\mu\nu}x^{\nu}+b_{\mu}\tag{13}$$

are affine functions. Comparing with the KE (11), we see that

$$ a_{\mu\nu}~\stackrel{(11)+(13)}{=}~-a_{\nu\mu} \tag{14}$$

is antisymmetric. The solution (13) correspond to $n(n-1)/2$ rotations and $n$ translations. Altogether we generate nothing but the $(n+1)(n+2)/2$ dimensional (global) conformal algebra. The main message is that local conformal deformations are rigid for $\color{red}{n\geq 3}$. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108472/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Thank you very much for a precise discussion and references. Although I see why $\mathbb{R}^2$ is special (since $2-2=0$) but it looks so tricky to me. The argument does not show why the conformal group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has infinite generators, however it shows perhaps conformal group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is different. I'm really thankful for the answer. At least it provides a reason.