# Conformal symmetry extension for super p-branes?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, branes

Conformal symmetry plays a vital role in string and superstring theories. Why can not we generalize conformal symmetry to objects of greater dimensions as branes? Where are we with this puzzle in 2020?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391624/2451

Comment: No because there is not asked what could be the generalization of conformal symmetry for p-branes I am asking for with this question.