# Inconsistent indices in the differential equation of infinitesimal conformal transformation

Tags: conformal-field-theory, differential-equations, textbook-erratum

Consider the equation from CFT,
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\nu} + \partial_{\nu}\epsilon_{\mu} = f(x)\eta_{\mu\nu}\tag{Yellow book eq. 4.3}
\end{equation}
which constrains the form of $\epsilon_{\mu}$ and eventually we get different types of conformal transformations in $d \geq 3$. If I apply $\partial_{\rho}$ on the above equation I would obtain
\begin{equation}
\partial_\rho\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\nu} + \partial_\rho\partial_{\nu}\epsilon_{\mu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} \partial_\rho f
\end{equation}
Now, the Yellow Book on CFT and [Introduction to Conformal Field Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-00450-6) says to permute indices of the above equation and we will get the following equations
$$\begin{align}
\partial_\rho\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\nu} + \partial_\rho\partial_{\nu}\epsilon_{\mu} &= \eta_{\mu\nu} \partial_\rho f\\
\partial_\nu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\mu} + \partial_\mu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\nu} &= \eta_{\rho\mu} \partial_\nu f\\
\partial_\mu\partial_{\nu}\epsilon_{\rho} + \partial_\nu\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\rho} &= \eta_{\nu\rho} \partial_\mu f
\end{align}\tag{BP p.8}$$
The above set of equations is given in [Introduction to Conformal Field Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-00450-6) on Pg. 8.

Now, if I consider the second equation in the above set of equations I will have
\begin{equation}
\partial_\nu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\mu} + \partial_\mu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\nu} = \eta_{\rho\mu} \partial_\nu f
\end{equation}
I can also write this equation as
\begin{equation}
\eta_{\rho\mu} \partial_\nu f = \partial_\nu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\mu} + \partial_\nu\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\rho}
\end{equation}
where I imported the structured from $\eta_{\mu\nu} \partial_\rho f = \partial_\rho\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\nu} + \partial_\rho\partial_{\nu}\epsilon_{\mu}$ and did the index change $\mu \to \rho$, $\nu \to \mu$ and $\rho \to \nu$.

Now a major inconsistency appears if we compare the last two equations,
\begin{equation}
\partial_\nu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\mu} + \partial_\nu\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\rho} = \partial_\nu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\mu} + \partial_\mu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\nu}
\end{equation}

We clearly see that the first two terms in the above equation cancel on both sides, but the second term remains. This means $\partial_\nu\partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\rho} = \partial_\mu\partial_{\rho}\epsilon_{\nu}$. There is no reason for them to be equal as there is no symmetry in the equation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For the proof, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391624/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the indices in the book you linked by Blumenhagen and Plauschinn are indeed wrong as stated by the authors in the [errata](https://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/blumenha/CFTerrata/index.html) for the book.