# What is special about conformal field theory in 2d?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, complex-numbers, spacetime-dimensions

In the most of textbooks about CFT, the special case of 2d is noticed in which complex coordinates play important role and it reads some results like the conformal transformation of energy-momentum tensor. Is this depends on some algebraic features of 2d case or just because of features of complex analysis like residue theorem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Topological/Geometrical justification for $\text{CFT}_2$ being special](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391624/2451)