# Conformal group and stereographic projection

Tags: conformal-field-theory

In Ginsparg's *Applied Conformal Field Theory* (http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028, on the bottom of p. 5) the following remark is made:

> *Indeed the conformal group admits a nice realization acting on $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$, stereographically projected to $S^{p,q}$ and embedded in the light-cone of $\mathbb{R}^{p+1,q+1}$.*

What does this mean?

Comment: This is mentioned in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/108532/2451).

Answer (score 0):

Your last $S$ should be an $R$.

The conformal group on is the set of transformations of $R^{p+q}$ that preserve angles ona $R^{p, q}$  is a Euclidean space with $p$ normal dimensions and $q$ imaginary ones; $S^{p,q}$ is presumably the unit sphere in this space; stereographic projections from the real space to the sphere will preserve angles. Then for each point on the sphere you can associate a future-pointing light ray passing through points in $R^{p+1,q+1}$, so each of the points on the sphere can be embedded in the larger light cone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. Can you elaborate on " Then for each point on the sphere you can associate a future-pointing light ray.."?

Comment: @leastaction sure, that part is simple. Suppose we take a plane and stereographically project its points onto the 2-sphere in the ordinary way; now the 2-sphere is embedded in $R^3$ in the normal way as a unit sphere centered at the origin. We can now shift to the $(+,-,-,-)$ space by associating each point $\vec r$ on this sphere with the four-vector $[1, \vec r]$ which has four-norm 0 -- so we've embedded the plane now in the set of four-vectors going through the origin. Notice that all of these processes are conformal.

Comment: This answer has some confusing typos.