# Local versus global conformal groups/algebras

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I am reading [Ginsparg's Conformal Field Theory Notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028) and I am somewhat puzzled by the use of global and local. Specifically, I understand that the generators of two-dimensional conformal transformations are not globally defined on the Riemann sphere $C \cup \infty$, and the only globally defined Virasoro generators are $\{l_0, l_1, l_{-1}\}$ (and the corresponding antiholomorphic versions).

But at later stage (page 9) he says

> Strictly speaking the only true conformal group in two dimensions is the projective (global) conformal group, since the remaining conformal transformations of (1.5) do not have global inverses on $C \cup \infty$.

What does he mean by "projective (global) conformal group"?

Comment: Precisely the group [$\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{C})$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group), which is generated by $l_{-1},l_0,l_1$.

Comment: The question (v1) is essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108472/2451 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/425371/2451