# Why is $\rm{Conf}(\mathbb{R}^{1,1}) = \rm{Diff}(S^1) \times \rm{Diff}(S^1)$ and not $ \rm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}) \times \rm{Diff}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, topology, lie-algebra

The Minkowski metric for $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ is
$$
ds^2 = dt^2 - dx^2 = du dv
$$
for coordinates
$$
u = t + x \hspace{1cm} v = t - x
$$

If you do any coordinate transformation that acts independently one $u$ and $v$,

$$
u = f(u') \hspace{1 cm} v = g(v')
$$
then the metric transforms as
$$
ds^2 = du dv = d(f(u')) d(f(v')) = f'(u') g'(v') du' dv'.
$$

Notice that the metric in $(u', v')$ coordinates is just a local rescaling of the original metric $dudv$. Therefore this is a conformal transformation. In fact, all conformal transformations of $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ are of this form.

Why then do I often see written 
$\rm{Conf}(\mathbb{R}^{1,1}) = \rm{Diff}(S^1) \times \rm{Diff}(S^1)$? Shouldn't it just be $\rm{Conf}(\mathbb{R}^{1,1}) = \rm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}) \times \rm{Diff}(\mathbb{R})$? Why is $\mathbb{R}$ "compactified" into $S^1$?

Comment: Often see where? Which page?

Comment: One example: "A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory" by Schottenloher

Comment: Another example is this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry except there's also a semidirect product with $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: On the wiki page it explicitly says that it's working with the compactified space.

Comment: But what's the point of working in compactified space for $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$? It doesn't seem to me like anything is gained, but I feel like there must be some point.

Comment: It's not of much use - if any at all - in physics. Minkowski space in physics is non-compact. If it were compact, then there would exist a time loop - $S^{1}$ - which means you can kill your ancestors and prevent your birth.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: The compactified definition follows a long & useful tradition in e.g. [projective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry) & [conformal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry) geometry, where one wants to treat infinity on the same footing as a point.

The upshot is that the local conformal [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid) 
$${\rm LocConf}(1,1)\tag{A}$$ 
for the 1+1D Minkowski plane is defined in mathematics as the set of locally defined conformal transformations on its [conformal compactification](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=conformal+compactification)$^1$
$$ \overline{\mathbb{R}^{1,1}}~\cong~\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1 .\tag{B}$$
${\rm LocConf}(1,1)$ contains 4 connected components. The connected component that contains the identity element is
$$ {\rm LocConf}_0(1,1)~\cong~ {\rm LocDiff}^+(\mathbb{S}^1)\times {\rm LocDiff}^+(\mathbb{S}^1).\tag{C}$$
For more details, see e.g. Ref. 1 and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108472/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/425371/2451) Phys.SE posts.

References:

1. M. Schottenloher, *Math Intro to CFT,* Lecture Notes in Physics 759, 2008; p. 37.

--

$^1$ It should be mentioned that the conformal compactification contains [closed timelike loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve), cf. above comment by Cinaed Simson.

Comment: In dimensions other than 1+1 D I can see the point for compactification because it allows you to include inversions. However, in 1+1 D I see no benefit to this compactification. The reason it disturbs me is because the Witt Algebra for example can be thought of as vector fields on $S^1$, which are different from vector fields on $\mathbb{R}$. Wouldn't the compactification change important facts about the algebra of diffeomorphisms? Again, I can see the usefulness in higher dimensions, but not in 1+1.

Comment: There are also inversions in 1+1D.