# 2-dimensional QFTs invariant under area-preserving diffeomorphisms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, yang-mills

In introductory textbooks & lecture notes on conformal field theory, it is usually stated that solving the highly nontrivial dimensional quantum field theory in 2 dimensions is possible due to the existence of the powerful infinite-dimensional symmetry. The symmetry under consideration is, of course, the Virasoro symmetry.

Now consider a completely different class of 2-dimensional field theories – those invariant under the group of area-preserving diffeomorphisms. Here the Lie algebra of the symmetry group consists of vector fields of vanishing divergence (on the flat $\mathbb{R}^2$, this means $\partial_{\mu} v^{\mu} = 0$). This is also an infinite-dimensional symmetry algebra, so naively, I expect it to be powerful enough to allow us to solve/classify 2-dimensional field theories invariant under area-preserving diffeomorphisms.

**My questions is:** to what extent can similar methods be applied to such theories? What are the most noteworthy results?

Finally, some motivation: at least classically, the 2-dimensional Yang-Mills theory is invariant under the area-preserving diffeomorphisms. We already know that there exists a non-abelian conformal gauge theory in 2 dimensions (the Wess-Zumino-Witten model) which is exactly solvable. Maybe the 2-dimensional Yang-Mills theory admits a similar definition, only its "blocks" are built by using "primary fields" of a different infinite-dimensional algebra rather than the Kac-Moody algebra?

I've heard that the 2-dimensional quantum Yang-Mills theory has been constructed rigorously by solving for certain heat kernels on the gauge group $G$. I wonder if there's an equivalent formulation which is more "Wightmanian" in its nature, specifically, one that utilizes explicitly specified $n$-point blocks that are used to build the correlation functions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97080/discussion-on-question-by-prof-legolasov-2-dimensional-qfts-invariant-under-are).

Comment: Have a look at [Iliopoulos 2018](https://www.epj-conferences.org/articles/epjconf/pdf/2018/17/epjconf_icnfp2018_02055.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be concrete let spacetime be 2D with Minkowski signature.

1. On one hand, the infinite-dimensional algebra 
   $${\rm locconf}(1,1)~=~{\rm Vect}(\mathbb{S}^1)\oplus {\rm Vect}(\mathbb{S}^1)\tag{1a}$$ of locally defined  conformal transformations in 2D is the algebra of [conformal Killing vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_Killing_vector_field) (CKVF), which is 2 copies of the real [Witt algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt_algebra), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108472/2451) Phys.SE post. In light-cone coordinates, a CKVF satisfies
   $$ \partial_{\mp}X^{\pm}~=~0\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad X^{\pm}=X^{\pm}(x^{\pm}). \tag{1b}$$
2. On the other hand, the infinite-dimensional algebra $${\rm sdiff}(1,1)\tag{2a}$$ of 2D area-preserving transformations is the algebra of [symplectic vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_field) (SVF), which includes the algebra of [Hamiltonian vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) (HVF). In light-cone coordinates, a HVF is of the form $$X^{\pm}~=~\pm\partial_{\pm}H, \tag{2b}$$
   where $H=H(x^+,x^-)$ is an arbitrary function.
3. The two infinite-dimensional algebras (1) & (2) behave naturally like oil & water, i.e. they almost don't mix: Their intersection is quite small, namely it is the 2D Poincare algebra $${\rm iso}(1,1),\tag{3}$$ which is generated by 1 Lorentz boost and 2 translations.
4. However, the algebra (2) is much bigger than the algebra (1) in the sense that it is often possible to embed a [Virasoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra)/[$W$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-algebra) inside (2), cf. Refs. 1-2. So in that sense the conformal methods apply to theories invariant under area-preserving diffeomorphisms, cf. OP's question.

References:

1. E. Sezgin, *Area-Preserving Diffeomorphisms, $w_\infty$ Algebras and $w_\infty$ Gravity,* [arXiv:hep-th/9202086](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9202086).
2. D.V. Artamonov, *Introduction to finite $W$-algebras,* [arXiv:1607.01697](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01697).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for writing this up. So because $sdiff$ is bigger than $locconf \sim Vir$, there should be additional constraints on the Virasoro representations? How hard is it to solve these constraints e.g. for the minimal models? Has Yang-Mills in 2d been constructed in this way and if it has, what is the corresponding CFT?

Comment: There is an error in the labelling of items in point 3, and possibly point 4. In particular, 3. seems like it should say "The infinite-dimensional algebras (1) and (2) behave..." and so I infer that 4. should say "However, the algebra (2) is much bigger than the algebra (1) in the sense..." I'm leaving this as a comment rather than editing, though, in case it is clear to someone with more expertise that 4., as written, is correct.

Comment: Hi @MatthewTitsworth. Thanks for the feedback. I tried to relabel for clarity.