How to wrap one's head around the conformal group $O(p\!+\!1,q\!+\!1)$ in a spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$?
By preserving angles obviously, har.. har...
In all seriousness, I can appreciate the Lorentz group for 4D being written $O(1,3)$ the same way we write our spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$. The Lorentz group is turned inside out in all undergraduate curriculums.
I get that in $O(2,4)$ the extra "temporal" part arises from out dilations and special conformal transformations but it remains very abstract to me and I haven't been able to find any source that goes through the process so that it is no longer something I just accept that has been derived and move on. I came upon the topic when looking at the compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$
Appreciate any help!

Are you asking for a reference to an explicit derivation of the conformal group in four dimensions? This is discussed in the yellow book.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628331/2451

Just to clarify do you mean the CFT book? I am just starting with qft so didnt want to jump 5 steps up, but looking that up might work if you'd recommend it.

If you want to learn about the conformal group, of course you should read a CFT book. Why would that information exist in a QFT textbook?

For what it's worth, the main point is that the conformal compactification $\overline{\mathbb{R}^{p,q}}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ naturally sits inside $\mathbb{R}^{p+1,q+1}$, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post and Ref. 1.
References:

M. Schottenloher, Math Intro to CFT, Lecture Notes in Physics 759, 2008; Chapter 1 & 2.

