# Conformal symmetry and group in arbitrary dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra, topology

As far as i understand, the full symmetry of relativity is conformal symmetry.
This is represented by the conformal group $ \operatorname{Conf}(1, 3) $
Of Minkowski spacetime which is $ \mathbb{R}^{1, 3} $

This has a very useful amount of information online, however i was wondering about a generalisation of this concept. Both for a pseudo-euclidean space of any signature $ \mathbb{R}^{p, q} $ and for any general manifold $ \mathcal{M} $ which would appear in general relativity.

Comment: The conformal group on ${\mathbb R}^{p,q}$ is $SO(p+1,q+1)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108472/2451